# Is it possible to show the total number of elements in the content css property?

Tags: css

I'm using the following css to display a step counter:

```
:before {
  content: "step " counter(fieldsets);
  counter-increment: fieldsets;
  /* Some more css */
}
```

But I was wondered if it was possible to display the total number of elements as well, like so:

```
:before {
  content: "step " counter(fieldsets) " of " total_number_of_fieldsets;
  counter-increment: fieldsets
  /* Some more css */
}
```

I would love it to be a pure css solution, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have something else that calculate the total_number_of_fieldsets count in the CSS, it is not possible.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EawLA/

You can show the total :after

Note that this will not work in IE<9 as pseudo elements are not supported

Comment: I'm aware of the poor backwards compatibility of this, and I think this solution isn't very pretty, but it does what I want it to do, thanks!

Comment: It does work in IE8, and IE has always supported at the very least `:first-line` and `:first-letter` pseudo-elements. It just didn't start supporting `:before` and `:after` until IE8+ and others in IE9/10.

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot inspect the DOM or use variables, therefore it cannot pull up this inforamtion.

Comment: That's not really true anymore, since you cán use counters now, and it is also possible to do `content: "step " counter(fieldsets) " of " attr(data-total-steps);` using a custom data attribute.

Comment: Thanks Jasper, All documentation says about using `"content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages)"` but I haven't managed to get it to work. I hadn't considers using data attr. thanks